# how to use global locale after it changes outside of component reactjs

Tags: javascript, webpack, momentjs

Project structure

```
src/
  components/
    forms/
      testForm.js
  helpers/
    time.js
  index.js
```

In the file time.js there is a helper function that create array of months

time.js

```
const getMonth() => {
  return moment.months() // calls before setting locale in index.js with english locale
}
```

moment.months() returns the list of months in the current locale.

Localization set up in index file

index.js

```
const locale =  getLocalization() // get localization from cookie
moment.locale(locale);
```

When project starts it bundles at first file time.js with locale 'en' and after that is bundles index.js file where moment locate is set up to 'ru' locale.

src/components/forms/testForm.js

```
import { createMonthList } from "../../helpers/time";

const monthList = createMonthList(); // options are always in English

function TestForm() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h4>List from helpers</h4>
      <ul>
        {monthList.map(month => {
          return <li key={month}>{month}</li>;
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

How to fix that? Options should be in language that was set up in index.js file, but it's always in English

Answer (score 0):

That reason was that I created list of month outside of component in module.

> Starting from entry points, webpack recursively builds a dependency
>   graph that includes every module your application needs, then bundles
>   all of those modules into a small number of bundles - often.

After webpack processed this project, this line will be executed when project starts, before localization will set up to German and before component TestForm will be mounted

`const monthList = createMonthList(); // used English locations which is used by default`

To call method `createMonthList` when component mounted. At that moment localization have been change to German.

Sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-of-moment-localization-37dj3?file=/src/components/forms/test.js:0-1090

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      monthList: createMonthList(); // used German locale which is set up in root file
    });
  }
```

TestForm Component

```
import React from "react";
import { createMonthList } from "../../helpers/time";


const monthList = createMonthList(); // used English locations which is used by default

class TestForm extends React.Component {
  state = {
    monthList: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      monthList: createMonthList() // used German localiztion which is set up in root file
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={styles.row}>
        <div>
          <h3>Wrong localization</h3>
          <h4>List's created outside of component</h4>
          <ul>
            {monthList.map(month => {
              return <li key={month}>{month}</li>;
            })}
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h3>Correct Localization</h3>
          <h4>List's created in component</h4>
          <ul>
            {this.state.monthList.map(month => {
              return <li key={month}>{month}</li>;
            })}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```